# python, class renaming vs inheriting

Tags: python, inheritance

Would it be correct to say that if some python class is well written,
then

```
class Subclass(BaseClass):
    pass
```

Should be sufficient to create a well behaved class with similar behavior to that of BaseClass?

(I am writing similar and not identical because for example)
SubClass.**name** or BaseClass.**qualname** would not be the same as their counterparts in BaseClass and this would possibly (probably) also extend to **str** and **repr** and possibly other metadata.

Would It make sense to use such "empty" inheritance to do class renaming for better semantics e.g. would you inherit collections.Countr to call it GuestsCount if you want to Count how many Adults / Children / Babies will be attending some event? or call it a "Polinomial" and use the count values to represent coefficients of some class that would represent variables to some power ( i.e.  X^2 or Y^3 ) and so on ?

EDIT:
I don't see how my Q is even related to dynamic renaming of class in any way AS IS.
I am talking about inheritance v.s. aliasing (or possibly just instantiating) but not about renaming an existing class dynamically nor about dynamically creating classes and issues related to how to name those dynamically created classes as discussed in the so called duplicate mentioned here  :(

Comment: Why don't you set a property with the value Adult/Child/Baby?

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/) helps you.

Comment: @quamrana This is not asking how to do it but whether it makes sense.

Comment: @Goyo: Well the first question from the OP asked whether the 'method' is sufficient. The answers in the linked question might be better ways.

Comment: @quamrana The answers might be better or worse ways but that is not what is being asked either.

Comment: Subclassing isn't a mean for convenience. I really don't think subclassing counter for naming reasons is a good idea nor a clear one if someone else reads your code. Why don't you just use alias? `GuestCounter = collections.counter`

Comment: @Spezi94, true, I could just have an instance of a Counter and call it GuestsCounter.... (Assuming I don't need ANY change of functionality).

Comment: @quamrana, I was trying to understand if I need anything else to have functional code... (e.g. an init dunder)

Comment: @Vinny, because in your case for example GuestCounter.__class__.name would probably be 'Counter' if I am not wrong here...

Comment: @epeleg if you want the object to be aware of its type, use an instance variable

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not common, I think it does makes sense. I'd refer you to [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1313447) by Robert Martin. Especially the last paragraph supports your rationale. Although the article deals with renaming functions, the same arguments could hold for renaming classes.

Additionally, concepts as different as `PersonCounter` and `Polynomial` will most likely soon diverge in terms of functionality too, although they start from the same class, so it makes sense to make them different classes.

Note: A closely related, common pattern in python frameworks, is subclasses that have only one class attribute

```
class GuestCounter(Counter):
    datatype=Person

class Polynomial(Counter):
    datatype=float
```

which could be useful if you create factory functions/type checkers/adapter functions for your objects

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "subclasses that have only one class attribute", when would they use this?(can you point to such an example in an actual framework?

Comment: also liked the article. It does go in the spirit of my own thoughts.

Comment: @epeleg: Take a look at the last 2 pages of this (from django source code): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/http/response/#HttpResponseNotModified. There are many http response classes that inherit from the parent response class, and just change the integer value of the http code. Similar patterns appear in many python frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

An additional advantage is that you could add attributes to the SubClass,
while it might not be possible for the BaseClass (dict or list for example).

Comment: thanks, those are the types of differences that I was trying to learn about

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense if you actually get better semantics, but in your examples you do not.

Having `AdultCounter` and `ChildCounter` suggests that counting adults is somewhat different than counting children, which is false and misleading. Not because they happen to share the same implementation (as explained in the [Uncle Bob`s article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1313447) linked in other answer, that would be fine) but because they are conceptually the same. Counting abstracts over any attributes of the items counted. Counting adults, children, sheep or a mix of them, it is all the same.

```
adults = AdultCounter({ev: ev.num_adults() for ev in events})
children = ChildCounter({ev: ev.num_children() for ev in events})
```

The ocasional reader would wonder what do these counters do that a bare `Counter` does not. After They would have to look at the definitions to find out the answer: nothing. So what's the point? The part that is actually different, the filtering, is done outside the counters.

And for polyomies, a `Counter` does not look like a good abstraction. Why would `mypoly.most_common()` return the term with the highest coefficient? Why does `poly1 + poly2` work while `2 * poly` does not and `poly1 - poly2` is buggy?

Comment: just to clarify that I did not intend to have an `AdultCounter`... I wanted to have a `GuestsCounter` that would hold in it items representing amounts of adults, kids and babies...